# handle escape characters in model attributes

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I have a HTML code like this

```
<c:forEach items="${commentList}" var="comment">
                <tr> 
                    <td>${comment.description}<br>
                        <div align="right">
                            <c:if test="${comment.userId == sessionUser.userId}">
                                <a href="javaScript:editComment('${comment.recordId}','${comment.description}');">Edit</a>
                                &nbsp<a href="javaScript:deleteComment('${comment.recordId}');">Delete</a>
                            </c:if>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And the `commentList` is a model attribute.

```
model.addAttribute("commentList", commentList); // array list in java
```

When the `comment.description` has escape character like the quotation mark (') then the below line will not work.

```
<a href="javaScript:editComment('${comment.recordId}','${comment.description}');">Edit</a>
```

error will be like `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

The line will have the string like `javaScript:editComment('2','aaa's hhh');`
I think there is a `qotation mark` after `aaa` which cause this issue.

How can I handle this situation.

there are lot's of places like this in my project. So what is the best way to do this.

Comment: You need to escape your parameters that you pass into the function either by a helper function or you can write a getter in your Java code that returns an escaped version of your attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me now,

But then has to do this for each and every location

```
<c:set var="string1" value="${comment.description}"/>
<c:set var="search" value="'" />
<c:set var="replace" value="\\'" />
<c:set var="string2" value='${fn:replace(string1, search, replace)}' />
<a href="javaScript:editComment('${comment.recordId}','${string2}');">Edit</a>
```